# Got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when using data provider pass in TestNG

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Here is part of my data provider method:

```
@DataProvider (name = "dataProvider1")
public static Object[][] dataProvider1()
{
    return new Object[][] {
            // Total sale 0.00
            { new Object[][]{{MSOECommissionCalculator.REPLACEMNET_ITEM, 0.00},
                    {MSOECommissionCalculator.REPLACEMNET_ITEM, 0.00},
                    {MSOECommissionCalculator.REPLACEMNET_ITEM, 0.00},
                    {MSOECommissionCalculator.REPLACEMNET_ITEM, 0.00},
                    {MSOECommissionCalculator.CONSULTING_ITEM, 0.00},
                    {MSOECommissionCalculator.MAINTENANCE_ITEM, 0.00},
                    {MSOECommissionCalculator.BASIC_ITEM, 0.00},
                    {MSOECommissionCalculator.MAINTENANCE_ITEM, 0.00}}, 0.00 },
```

When I use this data provider like:

```
    @Test (dataProvider = "dataProvider1", dataProviderClass = MSOECommissionCalculatorTestDataProvider.class)
public void testForProbationary(Object[][] sales, float assertCommission)
{

}
```

This generates the following error:

```
FAILED: testForProbationary([[Ljava.lang.Object;@380fb434, 0.0)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Answer (score 1):

0.00 is double, not float. Use 0 or 0.00F instead.